# Is it possible to display a robot model on top of the camera image in Rviz?

Tags: ros, rviz, tum-ardrone, camera, usb-cam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to display a 3D model of my drone on an image it had taken earlier. I have transforms, camera_info, position data, and timestamps, as well as the URDF and the model. However, I cannot seem to get that image and the robotmodel to appear in the same [visualization frame].

Is it possible to show the camera image in the same [visualization frame] as robotmodel, TF, and markers? This might allow for the ability to skew the image to represent its state when it was taken. Or, alternatively, can I display the robotmodel on the Camera frame?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221465/is-it-possible-to-display-a-robot-model-on-top-of-the-camera-image-in-rviz?/) by [masasin](https://answers.ros.org/users/25167/masasin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-11-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I understand you correctly, both are possible, although I'm not sure you'll end up with the result you are after.

> Is it possible to show the camera image in the same [visualization frame] as robotmodel, TF, and markers? This might allow for the ability to skew the image to represent its state when it was taken.

Not with the standard RViz plugins, but @Stefan Kohlbrecher (in a recently answered similar question: [Rviz: Display image in 3D scene](http://answers.ros.org/question/218502/rviz-display-image-in-3d-scene/#218759)) points to [vigir_ocs_rviz_plugin_mesh_display_custom](https://github.com/team-vigir/vigir_ocs_common/tree/master/vigir_ocs_rviz_plugins/vigir_ocs_rviz_plugin_mesh_display_custom), which should be capable of what you want. You'll probably need to massage it a bit though.

> Or, alternatively, can I display the robotmodel on the Camera frame?

I think this can be done using the *Camera* RViz panel. From the [wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/DisplayTypes/Camera) page:

> Creates a new rendering window from the perspective of a camera, and overlays the image on top of it.

This needs `CameraInfo` and (obviously) `Image` messages.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-11-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1